# WP7 ListPicker Set SelectedItem Problem

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a list picker propagated by two strings from an XML file, one a name and one a value.

```
        XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create("file.xml");
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

        var stringNames = from query in _doc.Descendants("string")
                     select new CustomValue
                     {
                         StringName = (string)query.Attribute("name"),
                         StringValue = (string)query.Attribute("value"),
                     };

        Listpicker.ItemsSource = stringNames;

    public class CustomValue
    {
        public string StringName             
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string StringValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

I can read the value OR name by using
    `((appname.pagename.CustomValue)(this.Listpicker.SelectedItem)).StringValue`

But i cannot set the selectedItem, if I used a method similar to the one above it changes the value of the StringValue in the class CustomValue.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you trying to set the `SelectedItem`? How is the binding set up? Can you set `SelectedIndex` ok?

Comment: Trying to set it using a string from an XML file stored in IO. 
I have tried both `ListPicker.SelectedItem = string` and ((appname.pagename.CustomValue)(this.Listpicker.SelectedItem)).StringValue = `string`
How would I used the `SelectedIndex`?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set `SelectedItem = "something"` as the collection holds instances of `CustomValue` not `string`. You have to make the seleccted item one of the availabel items.

Let's say you wanted to selected the first item in your collection. There are 2 ways to do this:

```
Listpicker.SelectedItem = stringNames.First();
```

or

```
Listpicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the selected index method - much easier and the other method didn't seem to work anyway... Thanks for your help :)