# set selecteditem to listpicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, selecteditem, listpicker

### XAML

```xml
 <DataTemplate x:Name="PickTmplItemTipo">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">               
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding tipo}" />                
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickTmplFullTipo">            
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,25,0,0">
                <TextBlock Name="lblTipo" Width="350" Text="{Binding tipo}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


<toolkit:ListPicker    
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="21,0,22,0" 
         Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Localizedresources.strTipoUni}" 
         FullModeHeader="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Localizedresources.strTipoUni}" 
         FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource PickTmplFullTipo}}" 
         ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource PickTmplItemTipo}}" 
         Name="lPickTipo" 
         TabIndex="0" 
         Height="98" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" 
         Tap="lPickTipo_Tap" 
         SelectionChanged="lPickTipo_SelectionChanged" />
```

### C#

**Fill listpicker:**

```cs
    List<tipos> _lstTipos { get; set; }
    private void cargaLista()
    {
        using (serviciosDBDataContext miDataContext = new serviciosDBDataContext(conn))
        {
            _lstTipos = miDataContext.tipos.ToList();
        }

        this.lPickTipo.ItemsSource = _lstTipos;
    }
```

**Set selecteditem:**

if I try this, returns this error "**SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value**."

```
this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = myStringValue;
```

And if I try the next thing, returns null error:

```
this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = lPickTipo.Items.First(x => (x as ListPickerItem).Content.ToString() == myStringValue);
```

But I can not to set by selectindex because I dont know which index equival

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you have a reference to the tipo (or if you override the tipo's equality operator):

  ```
  this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = yourTipo;
  ```

(for instance: `this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = _lstTipos[2];`)

- Otherwise:

  ```
  this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = this.lPickTipo.Items.OfType<tipos>().First(i => i.tipo == myStringValue);
  ```

Comment: thanks. I have tried this code: this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = this.lPickTipo.Items.OfType<tipos>().First(i => i.tipo == myStringValue);  and runs fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your list is bound to items of type `tipos` but you're trying to set the selected item to a string value, which it will not find. The `SelectedItem` property expects one of the bound items, or `null if no one is selected.

Try setting it to one of the values in the `_lstTipos` list, e.g:

```
this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = _listTipos.First();
```

PS. I have not tried this ListPicker control, but I believe this is how it usually works with WPF controls.

BTW looks like this is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715549/wp7-listpicker-set-selecteditem-problem).

Answer (score 1):

What if you try using a Linq request to retrieve the index?

*assuming you don't have any duplicate in your list*

```cs
this.lPickTipo.SelectedItem = _lstTipos.IndexOf(_lstTipos.Single(s => s == myStringValue));
```